# I want to add sub arrays to one single array keep id and value in php

Tags: php

My input array :

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [status_name] => Released
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [status_name] => Under Construction
    )
```

)
I want the output result :

```
Array (
[1] => Released
[2] => Under Construction
)
```

USe sub array id as output array key value and status_name as value array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is built into php as [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php). You would have:

```
$status_names = array_column($data, 'status_name', 'id');
print_r($status_name);
```

Bonus points on question as I had no idea this existed until looking for an answer for you.

Comment: Nice. I suspected something like this existed.

Comment: @mkumpan - Isn't it weird how sometimes the thing you need just exists and other times something that seems so obvious and simple doesn't? I added a note saying how to use the actual `id` field for the key using `array_combine` but then realized that `array_column` even lets you set another value from that array as the key. Too perfect.

Comment: As I mentioned in my own answer below, php array manipulation functions are extraordinarily powerful. Back in the day I used to code a little C++ and C#, and working with pre-mapped memory and static arrays is little fun, believe you me. :) Kudos, your answer takes the cake on this question.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
function reOrderArray($input_array)
{
    $result = array();
    foreach ($input_array as $sub_array)
    {
        $result[$sub_array['id']] = $sub_array['status_name'];
    }
    return $result;
}
```

There might be a built-in php function to do this, array functions in php are quite powerful. I am, however, woefully unaware of one.